# How to index a list with array formula? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, array-formulas

I am trying to use index to return values from a list created by an array formula. The array formula is:

`aRRAYFORMULA(match(filter(full_list,startDate=N4,locationID=L4,service=M4),ID_list,0))`

This array formula is essentially cross-referencing the filtered full_list with the ID_list to return positions of the ID's that are both in the full_list and ID_list. I'm now trying to turn the positions from the code above into the ID's found in the ID_list.

I've tried:

`aRRAYFORMULA(index(ID_list,ifna(match(filter(full_list,startDate=N3,locationID=L3,service=M3),ID_list,0),""),1))`

and

`arrayformula(index(ID_list,aRRAYFORMULA(match(filter(full_list,startDate=N4,locationID=L4,service=M4),ID_list,0))))`

but they only return the ID_list value for the first entry in the list. So say that the first formula returns 2 row positions, 4 and 20; the result of the formulas I've tried results is a single cell with the value for row position 4. The row position 20 is ignored.

Is there anything that I am doing incorrectly here and how do I fix this? Or, is there an easier way to achieve what I want, such as without an array formula?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: It's a very complicated sheet with over 5 other spreadsheets linked + queries in order to get the output of the full_list and ID_list. My issue is that I have an array formula that outputs a list of 4 row positions. However, when I use the index function around the arrayformula (like in the formulas I gave above) to get the exact values found at the row positions, only the first entry in the list returns an exact value from the indexed list. I'd like to have a list of the exact values found at the row positions given by the original array formula

Comment: if your sheet is sensitive, pls provide example mockup of what are you trying to achieve - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E3RjT2TsyMHJ9N6w7Okzu1EU0gQ8URwYkZp2UTomON8/edit#gid=0

Comment: have you tried a vlookup using curly brackets for your range?  that's often what people need when they think they need INDEX() in an arrayformula.

Answer (score 0):

I would forget about using INDEX altogether and just focus on an ARRAYFORMULA + FILTER + MATCH strategy:

```
=FILTER(ID_list,ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(MATCH(ID_list,full_list,0)))=TRUE)
```

If none of your ID_list values exist in full_list the formula will throw an error. If you want it to just report a blank, then add an IFERROR to your formula:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(ID_list,ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(MATCH(ID_list,full_list,0)))=TRUE),"")
```

Hope it works for you!